# AWS Cloudwatch not consistently logging lambda invocations

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

I have a lambda function and API Gateway setup that lets me invoke by lambda function by making a simple GET request. Sometimes a get request results in a log being made to Cloudwatch, sometimes it does not. I need to debug why certain query params result in an "internal server error", and so I need to be able to see the logs, but this is near-impossible due to the sporadic nature of the log writes.

Is this normal behavior that cloudwatch only sometimes creates logs for lambda invocations?

(I have not set up any fancy mechanisms such as e.g. checking request headers, etc.)

Comment: Could you describe how you find those logs in more details?

Comment: Are you aware that one CloudWatch log stream may contain multiple requests?

Comment: Cloudwatch logs have been reliable in PROD environment -I haven't seen missing requests. As per AWS documentation, they are suggesting to check quota limits - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/troubleshooting-execution.html#troubleshooting-execution-missinglogs

Enable AWS X-Ray for your Lambda function to get detailed traces of invocations, including request IDs, execution times, and status codes.